# ActiveRecord Associations should i be using 3 join tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

i currently have 3 tables and 3 join tables

Users
Projects
Materials

a User has many Projects and Materials

a Project has many Users and Materials

a Material has many Projects and Users

each of them have their respective join tables to one another

say a Material has a column "name" and "amount". How can i form the associations so that for the same instance of materials, it has a different amount for a Project and a User?

I am currently storing "amount" in their join tables so a UserMaterial and a ProjectMaterial has different "amounts". The issue with that is when i query the materials from a User, I would have to make 2 separate queries. One to get an array of the Material names from the Materials table,

```
user.materials
```

and another to get an array of the amounts from the UserMaterial.

```
user.usermaterials
```

Is there an issue/improvement with my associations? or is there a query method to combine those 2 arrays, attaching the correct name and amount to the correct id?

Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you query on user.materials, that will have to join through user_materials.  If you use `includes`, it can get both in one query.

```
user_materials = @user.user_materials.includes(:material)
```

Then, when you loop through, the user_material.material association will already be loaded and ready for you.

```
user_materials.each do |um| 
  name = um.material.name # material is already loaded
end
```

Comment: :D :D It works! Thanks! But it also works without the includes method. I was trying to find a way to put attributes of both queries into one object to be passed as a json into an api. That was another hurdle, but was able to do that using active model serializer (if anyone was interested)

Comment: It will work without includes, but that will cause a query for each user_material (this is an 'n+1' problem). The goal is to eager load if you have any looping/common queries.